# React gives 'URLSearchParams' is undefined in Edge v38

Tags: reactjs

Is React 16 still compatible with old Edge browsers such  38.14393.2068.0?
Yes I know this one is old, but it would be nice to support also older browsers... What EDGE browser versions are supported?

Any workaround for this error?

> 'URLSearchParams' is undefined in react-dom.development

Comment: maybe https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-search-params-polyfill can help?

Comment: According to https://caniuse.com/urlsearchparams URLSearchParams should be supported since Edge v17.